# how to determine the size in between the thumbnails (javascript/jquery slider)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A working sample here:

http://www.asstatauka.us.lt/slide/header2.html

I do not know how to determine the size in between the thumbnails (it should be three thumbnails close to each other). Also, how to display image title not only for the active thumbnail, but for all thumbnails? Please advice.

I am using: https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/blob/master/source/jquery.bxSlider.js

Answer (score 0):

For multiple Display options ,  give

```
displaySlideQty: 3,
```

For spacing between slides , manually set width/padding to `li` tag

Refer

http://bxslider.com/examples/display-move-multiple-slides-once-example-two